# How To play video like Twitter

Tags: ios

Hi i am newbie in Custom Player

I am developing a custom video player and want to play videos like twitter does

I have tableview of Video where videos are autoPlay but i want that if 4-5 rows contain a video type so i need to play only the center of video like twitter does

Right now if the visible cells are 3 then the each row play a video which i don't want

I want to play only single video of visible row which is in center.

How can i get the center row of visible row? i tried many code but could not able to get the center row or bottom of visible cell so i can play one video at a time.

Can anybody help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: upload code please